# Can a site template have both private and public pages in Liferay 7.x?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I have created a new site template, and I don't seem to be able to create public pages.
From the Page Tree I select "Public" and then click '+' and create the page.  But the page ends up in the Private site.

When I go to Site Builder > Pages, I don't even see separate public and private pages.
I thought that I was able to do this before (in Liferay 6.x) but I don't have a 6.x server available anymore to test on.  I can stand one up for curiosity, but that still wouldn't answer the need for this in the current version.

I need to create both pages from a template that will be used to create dozens - perhaps hundreds - of sites, and they need to inherit changes, so importing the public pages won't suffice.

Comment: 7.x is not quite enough for a focus of your question: in 7.4, the distinction between public and private pages goes away. Anyway: This does not seem to be programming related (see [help/on-topic]). I suggest you bring it over ot the [Liferay community](https://liferay.dev)

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't aware of a change in 7.4.  The version in question is 7.3 GA7.

Comment: I will ask the question in the Liferay Community as suggested, but in all honesty I have had better luck with getting answers here in the past.

Comment: FWIW, after more reading I was reminded of how we used to do this in Liferay 6.  Separate site templates for private and public pages, but the site creation form allowed selecting a different template for each and that seems to be the issue as currently there is only a single selection.  The "Create default pages as private (available only to members). If unchecked, they will be public (available to anyone)." check box seems to determine where the template's pages are added.